# The linkcolumn about django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I use django-tables2 to show some data in page,and now I want to make the cell link to some url,but the link url such as :

> url(r'^(?P\w+)/(?P\d+)/$', 'pool.views.pooldatestock',
>   name="pool_date_stock"),

and I read the documents of django-tables2,but I can't find some excample about this problem.

the tables show  in the page's url just like:http://127.0.0.1:8000/pool/20111222/

I try to write this in my tables.py :

> ```
> class PoolTable(tables.Table):
>     number = tables.LinkColumn('pool.views.pooldatestock', args=[A('number')])
>     date = tables.Column()
> ```

and then I try to write:

```
class PoolTable(tables.Table):
    number=tables.LinkColumn('pool.views.pooldatestock',
                             args=[A('date')],
                             kwargs=A('number')])
    date = tables.Column()
```

but it's error too...

somebody can tell me how to solve this problem?or should I create my own table view, without django-tables.

Thanks.and Merry Christmas:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It makes no sense for the `kwargs` parameter to be given a list, it should be given a `dict`. However as your URL doesn't used named groups, it doesn't need keyword arguments anyway. Just put both URL parameters in the `args` parameter:

```
class PoolTable(tables.Table):
    number = tables.LinkColumn('pool.views.pooldatestock',
                               args=[A('date'), A('number')])
    date = tables.Column()
```

Comment: Thanks bradley.ayers,I got it.I don't understand the args and kwargs before.:)Merry Christmas

Comment: Well `LinkColumn` tries to follow the same API as the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()` function. Have a look at the docs for that if you want to understand the arguments.