# Django tables 2: Hyperlinking items in a column

Tags: django

My app displays a table with many columns. I use Django tables 2 app to render the table. I am trying to make items in one column hyperlinked so that users can click. The url pattern is simple: `/contact/pk/`, for e.g. `/contact/2/`. This is what I have in my models:

```
#models.py

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    . . .

class ContactTable(tables.Table):

    name = tables.LinkColumn('contact_detail', args=[A('pk')])
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}

#urls.py

url(r'^contact/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.contact_view', name='contact_detail'),
```

However, the items do not get hyperlinked.

Comment: I think this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613542/the-linkcolumn-about-django-tables2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solved it:

```
class ContactTable(tables.Table):
    edit_entries = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="/contact/{{record.id}}">Edit</a>')

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

Comment: This adds the new column to the end of the table, is there anyway to determine the position of the column too?

Answer (score 5):

nixnotwin's solution uses hard-coded URLs.  To use reverse lookup urls:

```
class ContactTable(tables.Table):
    edit_entries = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{% url \'contact_detail\' record.id %}">Edit</a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing to `render_table` in your template? Just a regular `QuerySet`? My guess is you forgot to instantiate and configure the table in your view. Here is the example provided in the docs:

```
# tutorial/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2   import RequestConfig
from tutorial.models  import Person
from tutorial.tables  import PersonTable

def people(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'table': table})
```

If you do it like this, it should work fine.

**UPDATE:**

I know that the problem has already been resolved, but I noticed that the `name = tables.LinkColumn('contact_detail', args=[A('pk')])` line of code is within the `ContactTable` class's inner `Meta` class. It should be outside of the inner `Meta` class.

Comment: My form works fine while using the basic setup provided at Django tables 2 docs page. I want to add one more feature where the items in one columns get hyperlinked. E.g.: a table with name and age: John and 35. I want to e able to click on John and get lead to a page where I can modify his age. I have the edit form, but it needs to be linked to the data in the rendered tables with the url pattern I have mentioned above.

Comment: @nixnotwin What are you passing to `render_table` in your template?

Comment: Exactly what you have posted in your answer above. I have not made any changes to the default view mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @nixnotwin Have you done a sanity check? For example, change the class from "paleblue" to something else and see if that works?

Comment: I solved the issue. I have posted the solution as an answer here.

Comment: @nixnotwin I'm glad you got it resolved! I updated my answer with a piece of information that may or may not have also resolved your problem. I did it just in case somebody else stumbles upon my answer and finds my update useful.